# Configuring ArcGIS Pro Pop-up with same Image for every feature?

Tags: arcgis-pro, image, popup

As a step to a better understanding of my options for configuring ArcGIS Pro Pop-ups with an Image, I have gotten as far as right-clicking on a layer, choosing Configure Pop-ups to open the Configure Pop-ups pane, and clicking the Image button to see an Image element on that pane:

---

[image]

---

I then click the pencil button to edit the Image pop-up element where I want to attach the same image from a URL to every feature.

To do that I thought it might be as simple as finding an image at Wikimedia Commons like https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Ship#/media/File:DANA_2004_ubt.jpeg and copy/pasting that URL in as the Source URL:

---

[image]

---

but when I did that, and back arrowed to test it, the pop-up that appeared was as below:

---

[image]

---

How can I get this pop-up to show me the image that I tried to link in using that URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You entered a [link to a web page](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Ship#/media/File:DANA_2004_ubt.jpeg)[1]* as the *Source URL*, not a [direct link to the image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/DANA_2004_ubt.jpeg)[2].

```
  [1]: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Ship#/media/File:DANA_2004_ubt.jpeg  # Web page with image viewer
  [2]: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/DANA_2004_ubt.jpeg  # Image direct link
```

[image]

[image]

* For info, the web page you linked to uses the [WikiMedia Media Viewer](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:Media_Viewer):

> **What is Media Viewer?**
>
> Media Viewer is a new multimedia browser that aims to improve the viewing experience on Wikipedia and Wikimedia sister projects. It lets you view images in larger size, with useful information about their contents, authors and related metadata. It also offers a number of tools to share, download or embed media files.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of [@user2856](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/342381/63384) works well given that you need the entire layer in the table of contents to view the same image. However, if you want each individual geometry of the vector layer to view a different pop-up image you need to store the image link inside a text field in the attribute table as follows:

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/DANA_2004_ubt.jpeg" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
```

[image]

Then call a pop-up as Text not Image:

[image]

and select the field that contains the link. In this example the field name is `Link`:

[image]

Now you can see different image for each geometry - polygon in this example.

[image]

[image]

The advantage of using this method is that you can control the size of the image to make it smaller or bigger using the style CSS included in the attribute table `style="width:100px;height:100px;`

Comment: I'd seen this technique in an Esri HowTo at https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000019312 but wanted to be able to do something simpler along the way to doing that.

Comment: @PolyGeo It depends on what would you like to show in the pop-up, for example, one image per feature class or one image per feature (individual point or polygon). In my understanding, adding image in the pop-up will add one image per feature class (all points or polygons will have one image), but the adding an image in the attribute table as `img src` will add a different image for each feature.

Comment: Yes - attaching different images for each feature is something I'll be doing just a little later.  For now I only want to do a simpler teaching exercise by attaching the same image to every feature.